# php copy() does not work

Tags: php, copy

I want to do a simple copy using a ajax call. this is my code but it does not work . i kepp getting : a copy(../../images/merchant/particulars/208/) failed to open stream: Is a directory in         some/filepath on scriptname.php line x , kind of error.

```
corrected code: 

$dir_to_make = '../../images/merchant/particulars/'.$copytothisstore;
$dir = '../../images/merchant/particulars/'.$copytothisstore.'  /'.$copyvalue;
$image_to_copy = '../../images/merchant/particulars/'.$copyfromthisstore.'/'.$copyvalue;






    if(is_file($image_to_copy)){

        //chk if there is a folder created for this store
        if(!is_dir($dir_to_make)){
              mkdir($dir_to_make, 0755);  
              chmod($dir_to_make, 0755);

              //copy the image 
              if (!copy($image_to_copy,$dir)) {
                  echo "failed to copy $image_to_copy\n";
              } else {
                  echo"all is well!!";
              }

           } else {
               chmod($dir_to_make, 0755);
               if (!copy($image_to_copy,$dir)) {
                  echo "failed to copy $image_to_copy\n";
              } else {
                  echo"all is well!!";
              }

           }


           echo"$image_to_copy does exist!";
        } else{
            echo"$image_to_copy does not exist!";
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please read your error.

```
copy(../../images/merchant/particulars/208/) failed to open stream: Is a directory in some/filepath
```

**It says that your source file is not a file, but directory.**

Simple debugging could always solve your problems:

```
$image_to_copy ='../../images/merchant/particulars/'.$copyfromthisstore.'/'.$copyvalue;
echo $image_to_copy; // yes, that could give you the answer
```

It will show you, **that `$copyvalue` in you example is empty.**

---

If you wonder why this is returning `TRUE`...

```
if(file_exists($image_to_copy)){
```

..it's because directory `../../images/merchant/particulars/208/` does exists.

As manual says:

- [file_exists() - Returns TRUE if the file or directory specified by filename exists; FALSE otherwise.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

You should change it to:

```
if(is_file($image_to_copy)){
```

- [is_file() - Returns TRUE if the filename exists and is a regular file, FALSE otherwise.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php)

---

Another thing is destination shuld be file as well:

```
copy($image_to_copy, $dir.'file.jpg');
```

Manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: ok. I tried this if(is_file($image_to_copy)){ and i get the same error. I think the problem is i dont understand the error message.    copy(../../images/merchant/particulars/208/) failed to open stream: Is a directory in some/filepath. The path in the error is meant to be the destination folder not the path to the image to copy. so i don't understand. the right parameter are placed in the correct location. copy($image_to_copy,$dir);

Comment: `$copyvalue` in you example is empty. Please update your question with new code.

Comment: It does have a value. in the error i have my own debugging echo : ../../images/merchant/particulars/652/cibc.jpg does exist!

Comment: @LeocrawfStewart Peter's answer was very clear. `copy()` is meant to copy a file to another file. The 2nd argument must be a *file*, not a *folder*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing a simple thing. Here is a simple example on how to use `copy()`

```
$file = 'path/to/filename.ext'; // Example: http://adomain.com/content/image.jpg

$destination_folder = 'path/of/the/destination/folder';
//example: $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/content/files/"


// Execute the copy function
copy($file, $destination_folder.'/newFilaname.ext');
```

Answer (score -3):

Use this function

```
!move_uploaded_file($image_to_copy, $dir)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: It doesn't appear that the OP is dealing with uploaded files.

Comment: I just got an epiphany. In all my reading i always thought that you pass to params to to copy(). I always that that this is how it works copy('images/298/image.jpg','images/296/'). I just realized it needs to be this copy('images/298/image.jpg','images/296/image.jpg');

Comment: what's with the `!` at the start of the line?